# Как стереть несколько символов в консоли?

Tags: c++, консоль

Подскажите как в с++ удалить несколько предыдущих символов?Именно несколько 
(не все system("cls")'ом вытереть).Может функция какая есть или другие способы?

Comment: вы хотите стиреть с буфера или вы хотите, чтоб программа их не читала?

Comment: Стирать из буфера

Comment: Когда пишете в консоли, там есть курсор, который указывает на текущий символ.  установите курсор , движением влево (вправо),на ненужные символы и нажмите на кнопку delete

Comment: В общем случае консоль это принтер и как принтер консоль не имеет операции стирания. Если Вам так уж нужно стирать символы из консоли, то Вам надо организовать свой буфер перед консолью, из которого стирать символы. Но вообще-то желание стирать из консоли это плохой признак. Что-то не так в постановке задачи. В норме таких желаний возникать не должно.

Comment: Ну вот у меня задача например ввести возраст.Если он меньше 1 то вывести на консоль input error.И что бы не захламлять экран нужно стереть input error и пусть человек заново вводит значение.Если опять неправильно, опять ошибку и.т.д.

Comment: [что бы не захламлять экран нужно стереть input error и пусть человек заново вводит значение] Для этого есть скроллинг экрана. Переводите строку, печатаете диагностику, снова переводите строку и снова предлагаете ввести данные.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а можно хоть пример какой-то?А то плюсы всего пару месяцев изучаю.Ещё на вводе-выводе не останавливались особо.Не совсем понимаю о чём речь

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать символ подстановки `\b`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Abcg";
    cout << "\b";
    cout << "def" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то оно не везде работает.А функций нету никаких?

Comment: Единственное что могу предложить это ререндер

Answer (score 1):

си

```
// Удалить символы в консоли
void backspace(int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf_s("\b \b");
}
```